# keyboard shortcut that will paste the output of a bash command

Tags: linux, bash, kde-plasma

I want to be able to paste the output of different bash scripts into an open office document.

If I run the script in the terminal it works... how to get that output pasted through a keyboard shortcut (in KDE linux)

Any thoughts welcome!

Comment: Other than piping to `xsel`?

Comment: Not necessarily what you are looking for, but if your system is configured for sending mail (eg. with a MTA such as Postfix or Sendmail) using an external SMTP server, you could pipe the output to any utility that can send email, such as `mailx`.  This has the advantage of being independent from the terminal emulator.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams  `xsel` did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe output to `xsel`.

(Posting answer from comment so you can mark it as accepted and this question won't appear on list of unresolved questions)